# redirect stderr to a file in call-process-region

Tags: shell, process, error-handling, subprocess

I have been reading the documentation for `call-process-region` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) and I am trying to redirect stderr to a file. from the the documentation, this looks correct

```
(call-process-region beg end perltidy-executable t '(t (:file "/tmp/tidy")))
```

however when I try to run it I get the following error

`Wrong type argument: stringp, (:file "/tmp/tidy")`

it works without errors if I use

```
(call-process-region beg end perltidy-executable t '(t nil))
```

but that causes stderr to be lost.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `(:file )` just give the error file as second element in the list.

```
BUFFER can also have the form (REAL-BUFFER STDERR-FILE); in that case,
REAL-BUFFER says what to do with standard output, as above,
while STDERR-FILE says what to do with standard error in the child.
```

So you would call:

```
(call-process-region beg end perltidy-executable t '(t "/tmp/tidy"))
```